# How to use GrahpiQL to upload file in grahpql?

Tags: graphql, graphiql, react-relay

I am a newbie in graphql and I am trying to create a sever which will take few parameters and a few files (like images) as parameters in mutation.

I am using graphql-yoga and it is very clear how to implement it using graphql-yoga.

My question is how to test it? 
How can I test the file upload from graphql playground?

I am going to use react-relay so are there any examples to do it in react-relay.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Neither GraphiQL nor GraphQL Playground support file uploads. You can use a standalone client like [Altair](https://altair.sirmuel.design).